# where is indexes stored in NTFS when enable it?

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, search, windows-search

When we enable indexing in NTFS Partition, where is saved?

How many bits were used?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995846.aspx) says:

> Several new NTFS5 features rely on a fundamental NTFS feature called attribute indexing.

For example if I have a 500GB Hard Disk and it is full of files 
(by 10 million files), and I have 20 MB free!!! Is it correct to enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data. is where the index files are stored. 
No, if you only have 20mb of hard drive space left you shouldn't use indexing. You should go to my computer, right click on the drive > properties > general tab > disk cleanup. If it manages to free up a few gigs, I would defrag the drive.

Comment: this means that : if my windows drive in separate Hard disk (C:), this free space on D: not needed? this means that didn't need space on that drive? or _Program Data_ created on D:?

Comment: @saber
I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking here.